# why my function total doesn't work in calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I need a small help.
I'm at the beginning of my way with programming in Javascript. I'm trying do a calculator. I have a problem with '='. Don't show me a score, when I've clicked on it. Please, tell me, where I do a mistake?

here is my git: https://github.com/madzikowael/calculator/blob/main/script.js

```
const calculate = () => {
    let action;
    if(!previousOperation || !actualOperation) {
        return
    }

    const previous = parseFloat(previousOperation)
    const actual = parseFloat(actualOperation)

    if(isNaN(previous) || isNan(actual)){
        return
    }

    switch (operation) {
        case '+':
            action = previous + actual
            break
        case '-':
            action = previous - actual
            break
        case '×':
            action = previous * actual
            break 
        case '÷':
            if(actual === 0) {
                deleteScore()
                return 
            }
            action = previous / actual
            break
        case '^':
            action = Math.pow(previous, actual)
            break
        case '√':
            action = Math.pow(previous, 1 / actual)
            break
        case '%':
            action = previous / 100 * actual
            break
        case 'log':
            action = Math.log(previous) / Math.log(actual)
            break
        default:
            return
    }

    actualOperation = action
    operation = undefined
    previousOperation = ''
}

const chooseOperation = (operator) => {
    if(actualOperation === '') {
        return
    }
    if(previousOperation !== '') {
        const previous = previousOperation.innerText
        if(actualOperation.toString() === '0' && previous[previous.length - 1] === '÷') {
            deleteScore()
            return
        }
        calculate()
    }

    operation = operator;
    previousOperation = actualOperation;
    actualOperation = '';
}


const updateScore = () => {
    actualScore.innerText = actualOperation;

    if(operation != null) {
     previousScore.innerText = previousOperation + operation
    } else {
        previousScore.innerText = ''
    }
    
 }


numbers.forEach((numb) => {
    numb.addEventListener('click', () => {
        addNumber(numb.innerText);
        updateScore();
    })
})

del.addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteNumber();
    updateScore();
})

operators.forEach((operator) => {
    operator.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chooseOperation(operator.innerText);
        updateScore();
    })
})

total.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculate();
    updateScore();
})

clean.addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteScore();
    updateScore();
})
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this line:

```js
if(isNaN(previous) || isNan(actual)){
     return
}
```

the function `isNan()` does not exist. Therefore an error is thrown and the `calculate()` function is aborted.

Replace it by:

```
if(isNaN(previous) || isNaN(actual)){
     return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see it's just a typo, change `isNan(actual)` to `isNaN(actual)`.

As i'm unable to edit the actual question, added code snippets here.

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const operators = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
const clean = document.querySelector('.clean');
const del = document.querySelector('.delete');
const total = document.querySelector('.total');
const previousScore = document.querySelector('.previous-operation');
const actualScore = document.querySelector('.actual-operation');

let actualOperation = '';
let operation = undefined;
let previousOperation = '';

const calculate = () => {
    let action;
    if(!previousOperation || !actualOperation) {
        return
    }

    const previous = parseFloat(previousOperation)
    const actual = parseFloat(actualOperation)

    if(isNaN(previous) || isNaN(actual)){
        return
    }

    switch (operation) {
        case '+':
            action = previous + actual
            break
        case '-':
            action = previous - actual
            break
        case '×':
            action = previous * actual
            break 
        case '÷':
            if(actual === 0) {
                deleteScore()
                return 
            }
            action = previous / actual
            break
        case '^':
            action = Math.pow(previous, actual)
            break
        case '√':
            action = Math.pow(previous, 1 / actual)
            break
        case '%':
            action = previous / 100 * actual
            break
        case 'log':
            action = Math.log(previous) / Math.log(actual)
            break
        default:
            return
    }

    actualOperation = action
    operation = undefined
    previousOperation = ''
}

const chooseOperation = (operator) => {
    if(actualOperation === '') {
        return
    }
    if(previousOperation !== '') {
        const previous = previousOperation.innerText
        if(actualOperation.toString() === '0' && previous[previous.length - 1] === '÷') {
            deleteScore()
            return
        }
        calculate()
    }

    operation = operator;
    previousOperation = actualOperation;
    actualOperation = '';
}

const addNumber = (numb) => {
    if(numb === '.') {
        if(actualOperation.includes('.')) {
            return
        }
        numb = '.'
    }
    actualOperation = actualOperation.toString() + numb.toString();
}

const deleteNumber = () => {
    actualOperation = actualOperation.toString().slice(0, -1)
}

const updateScore = () => {
    actualScore.innerText = actualOperation;

    if(operation != null) {
     previousScore.innerText = previousOperation + operation
    } else {
        previousScore.innerText = ''
    }
    
 }

const deleteScore = () => {
    actualOperation = ''
    operation = undefined
    previousOperation = ''
    
}


numbers.forEach((numb) => {
    numb.addEventListener('click', () => {
        addNumber(numb.innerText);
        updateScore();
    })
})

del.addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteNumber();
    updateScore();
})

operators.forEach((operator) => {
    operator.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chooseOperation(operator.innerText);
        updateScore();
    })
})

total.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculate();
    updateScore();
})

clean.addEventListener('click', () => {
    deleteScore();
    updateScore();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dela+Gothic+One&display=swap');

*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Dela Gothic One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #6c757d;
}
.calculator {
    margin: 25px;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 80px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 80px);
    min-height: 70vh;
}
.score {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    background-color: #333533;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 25px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
.previous-operation {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
.actual-operation {
    font-size: 30px;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #333533;
    background: #242423;
    outline: none;
}
button:hover, button:focus {
    background: rgba(36, 36, 35, .95);
}
.col-two {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
.row-two {
    grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Najlepszy kalkulator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="score">
                <div class="previous-operation"></div>
                <div class="actual-operation"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="clean col-two">AC</button>
            <button class="delete">DEL</button>
            <button class="operator">√</button>
            <button class="operator">÷</button>
            <button class="number">1</button>
            <button class="number">2</button>
            <button class="number">3</button>
            <button class="operator">^</button>
            <button class="operator">&times</button>
            <button class="number">4</button>
            <button class="number">5</button>
            <button class="number">6</button>
            <button class="operator">%</button>
            <button class="operator">-</button>
            <button class="number">7</button>
            <button class="number">8</button>
            <button class="number">9</button>
            <button class="operator">log</button>
            <button class="operator row-two">+</button>
            <button class="number">.</button>
            <button class="number">0</button>
            <button class="total col-two">=</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```